# Pygame Animated Object is not Drawn over

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I am writing a simple python game for class using pygame. I have coded for a short amount of time but have not used graphics until this project. I have already created a 'fireball' that moves from the player to the point clicked.
I am working on a warrior, he has a sword the travels with him. I also have got the slash-looking motion I want. You press the space bar to have the sword change angles then it comes back up to its regular position. The problem I am having is that once the image/object(sword) is drawn in the down position it stays in that position. Though the original image rises back to the original position. I was hoping someone would have a point in the right direction. This is my first graphical game. I know this usually has something to do with what line the object is drawn on in the main, however, i have messed around with that quite a bit with no luck.  Also, if I am going about this incorrectly don't hesitate to say anything.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

```
def __init__(self, name):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.name = name
    self.level = 1
    self.xp = 0
    self.health = 100
    self.power = 100
    self.disc = 0
    self.currentAtk = 1


def draw(self, screen):
    screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

def update(self):
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[K_SPACE]:
        if self.disc == 1 and self.currentAtk == 1:
            self.warsword.stab()
```

class Sword(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

```
image = pygame.image.load('images\\sword.png')

def __init__(self, x1, y1, angle = -25, stabtime = 5):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.angle = angle
    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(Sword.image, self.angle)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x, self.rect.y = x1, y1
    self.stabtime = stabtime
    self.repeat = 2

def update(self):
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[K_a] and self.rect.x >= 72:
        self.rect.x -= 1
    if key[K_d] and self.rect.x <= 572:
        self.rect.x += 1
    if key[K_w] and self.rect.y >= 154:
        self.rect.y -= 1
    if key[K_s] and self.rect.y <= 309:
        self.rect.y += 1

def draw(self, screen, x, y):
    screen.blit(self.image, (x, y))

def stab(self):
    if self.angle != -90 and self.stabtime == 5:
        self.angle = -90
        self.rect.y += 15
    if self.stabtime >= -5:
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.angle)
    else:
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.update(self)
    self.stabtime -= 1
```

class Warrior(Player):

```
image = pygame.image.load('images\\warrior.png')
SwordX = 0
SwordY = 0
def __init__(self, name, x, y):
    super(Warrior, self).__init__(name)
    self.disc = 1
    self.image = Warrior.image
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y
    Warrior.SwordX = self.rect.x + 12
    Warrior.SwordY = self.rect.y + 10
    self.warsword = Sword(Warrior.SwordX, Warrior.SwordY)
    atks.add(self.warsword)
```

def main():

```
chars = pygame.sprite.Group(())
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
a = Warrior('Fago', 250, 200)
chars.add(a)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
while True:

    chars.update()
    atks.update()
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load('images\\arena.png'), (0,0))
    atks.draw(screen)

    chars.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
    CLOCK.tick(75)
    pygame.event.pump()
```

main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. First store a copy of the original image in the `Sword` class and give it a `stabbing` attribute. Calling `stab()` will rotate the image and set `self.stabbing = True`. Now in the `update` method you look if it's still stabbing, decrement the `self.stabtime` and if it's `<= 0` reset the image and angle.

```
SWORD_IMAGE = pygame.image.load('images\\sword.png').convert()

class Sword(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x1, y1, angle=-25, stabtime=30):
        super().__init__()
        self.angle = angle
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(SWORD_IMAGE, self.angle)
        self.orig_image = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x1, y1))
        self.stabtime = stabtime
        self.stabbing = False

    def update(self):
        if self.stabbing:
            if self.stabtime <= 0:
                self.reset_stab()
            self.stabtime -= 1

    def stab(self):
        self.angle = -65
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.orig_image, self.angle)
        self.stabbing = True

    def reset_stab(self):
        self.stabtime = 30
        self.image = self.orig_image
        self.angle = -25
        self.stabbing = False
```

Side notes:

Don't load images again and again from your hard disk inside the while loop, just load them once globally and reuse them in the program. Also, convert images with the `convert()` or `convert_alpha()` methods to improve the performance.

Don't call `pygame.key.get_pressed()` more than one time, call it in the while loop and then pass the `key` tuple to the objects that need it.

Comment: I appreciate it(along with the side notes), I always like to know what can be done better. I sort of got it to work but I am going to try to implement this, it seems to be a lot cleaner. Thanks again! :)